# Transforming function while maintaining constant definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transformation

Suppose we have the function $f(x) = x$. The definite integral of this function from 1 to a is:

$$
\int_1^a x dx = \frac{a^2-1}{2}
$$

Now suppose we want to make $f(x)$ nonlinear, so it may take the form of something like $g(x) = x^2$. However, we want to constrain $g(x)$ so that its integral is the same as that of $f(x)$ despite the nonlinear term. Is there a general methodology we can use to make this transformation?

Comment: You need to be more specific, for instance it is always possible to multliply $x^2$ by the ratio of the two integrals, i.e. $g(x)=\frac{\int_1^a x\,dx}{\int_1^a x^2\,dx}x^2=\frac{3(a^2-1)}{2(a^3-1)}x^2$ would work, but this appear to be very artificial to me.

Comment: I agree with @zwim, you need to be more descriptive...  You could do something like changing the integration limits, setting $\int_c^d{x^2\, dx}=\frac{a^2 - 1}{2}$, in which case you would still need another function to define $c$ in terms of $d$...  There are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-variable definite integral $\int _a ^b f(x)dx$ is (Riemman's) the area between the $y=0$ axis and the $f(x)$ function, limited by $a \le x \le b$.

You can find infinite different $f(x)$ functions that have the same area within the same limits.

Think of a rectangle, can be the same area as a triangle, or an ellipse, etc.